# Hyperion Error : EPMHFM-66024 - No Port is available from the port range configured by the user: 10001- 10020

Tags: oracle, hyperion

Installed Hyperion 11.2, and after a few days started to get the following message:

```
EPMHFM-66024 - No Port is available from the port range configured by the user: 10001- 10020.
```

Is there a setting that I need to update / missed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

similar to 11.1.2.4, each app needs at least 2 ports per application, so in theory, having more than 10 applications in the env can be a cause but I see these errors happening with just 1 app, as other processes would use ports within the hfm port range defined.

I suggest:

- Check port range set for HFM datasources > from your message we see it is 10001 - 10020.
- Check if you have any non-HFM processes making use of that port range. In case of conflicts, you may need to use another port range for these processes, or redefine the range for HFM.
- Other considerations:
- TCP Dynamic Port Range should have this HFM port within it.
- Each application requires at least 2 ports of the range, so for more of 10 apps running, port range should be extended.
- Even with less apps, you can experience issues, cause of time_wait.

Hope this helps, Thanks.

Comment: Hi Klausen, thanks for the reply. I have only configured for HFM and checked that there are no port conflicts. Quick question on the time_wait, what would be the best option for this and where would I change this. Thanks

Comment: Hi Graham, how / where to change it is explained here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314053/tcp-ip-and-nbt-configuration-parameters-for-windows-xp (Check TcpTimedWaitDelay). Rather than propose a particular value, I would reduce and test if it affects positively. Tuning is always trial / error exercise depending on the environment.

Comment: Hey GrahamD, 
I did not replied you before, my apologies for that.
For adjusting the Time_Wait parameter, you will need to use the Windows Registry, I can suggest 30 seconds value to something to start with. Quick Googling would show you steps to follow if still needed.
Thanks.